# HTML automatically resize button and font size for phones in a form box

Tags: html, css, button, resize, autoresize

So I'm still trying to get the hang of html and css, so it could be what I want to do needs a completely different approach.

So right now when I view my website on my phone the form will auto resize, but my button currently doesn't.

However as you can see from the code, I have both the button and font size pretty big. What I would like is for a way to automatically resize the button and the font size to fit when viewed on a phone and tablet.

Below is the css code for my button.

Thanks

```
<form>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="field-style field-split align-left set-width" placeholder="Your Email" />
</br>
</br>
<btn>
<input type="submit" name="Subscribe"  value="GET THE FREE COURSE NOW" id="submit" />
</btn>
</form>

.form-style-9 btn input[type="button"],
.form-style-9 btn input[type="submit"] {
  background: #3cd934;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cd934, #2b8016);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cd934, #2b8016);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cd934, #2b8016);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cd934, #2b8016);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cd934, #2b8016);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4;
  -moz-border-radius: 4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 27px;
  padding: 11px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form-style-9 btn input[type="button"]:hover,
.form-style-9 btn input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #256e13;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #256e13, #1d520f);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #256e13, #1d520f);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #256e13, #1d520f);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #256e13, #1d520f);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #256e13, #1d520f);
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    btn {
        width: 50px;
        font-size:10px;
    }
}
```

The above is saying if the screen size is `<= 300px` then apply these rules.